# Save state and MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

How to save state (eg. by PhoneApplicationService) and don't break mvvm principles.

When application goes to "deactivated" state I want to preserve model object (eg. bounded to a form) and restore it when application will be resume.

Where I should place a logic of "save state mechanism". In view or viewmodel?

Disadvantage place in viewmodel:
I want to use my mvvm in other platform (Win8) and I want to make my mvvm to be maximum independent from platform.

I been thinking about one event in viewmodel where view can be handled moment of model object creaction and save it in platform specific storage.

or

make service to save state based on interface and register it in ViewModelLocator.

Comment: I would use the service because it is available to all view models

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote an article about exactly this, and I created a NuGet package for this:

Article: http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/03/13/tombstoning-made-easy-in-windows-phone-mvvm/

NuGet: Install-Package WindowsPhone.MVVM.Tombstone

You can read the article to see how to use the package.

The package basically allows you to apply an attribute to save all the properties upon tombstoning and restores them automatically. You just need to handle two page events.